# How to remove EJB2.1 Stateless session bean

Tags: java, ejb-2.x, stateless-session-bean

Greetings all,
I have a question: How to remove an EJB session bean (especially Stateless beans) ?

There's of course remove() method, however it cannot be called while the session object is in transaction i.e. session bean A is called by another session bean B in it's business method.

Comment: I think you under the misapprehension that you have to remove stateless beans to free resources or something.

Answer (score 0):

A Stateless bean **can't be removed by the client**, in fact they *never "die"*, that's because *the container uses a pool of stateless session beans* to handle user's request.

A stateful bean is taken out from the pool and attached to a client **only while the method call lasts**, after that, the container **put it back into the pool**. Oddly, *the remove method is only useful to realease resources for stateful and entity beans*, the container always ignores the remove method for stateless session beans.